Azure functions decoding error for IotHub device connection state message schema
I've a Azure function in Python 3.11 and Linux hosting.
It is throwing an error when trigger is service bus queue message,
which is having IoTHub device connection state message with schema like this
schema.Result: Failure Exception: ValueError: cannot convert value of field 'SequenceNumber' in trigger metadata into int: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '000000000000000001dummy100000004000000000000000000, File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.11/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 570, in _handle__invocation_request args[pb.name] = bindings.from_incoming_proto

function code
@app.service_bus_queue_trigger(arg_name="azservicebus", queue_name="iothub-device-lifecycle-events",
                               connection="ServiceBusConnection")
def genaiot_servicebus_dlm_queue_trigger(azservicebus: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    logging.info('Python ServiceBus Queue trigger processed a message: %s',
                azservicebus.get_body().decode('utf-8'))


Please share your code which you have tried and How you are reading SequenceNumber?

It is failing on trigger itself, adding my code in above @Harshitha

I could see the same issue when trying to trigger a Python Function App based off the message body generated by Device Connect/Disconnect status event originating from IoT Hub.
The message body generated by this event consists only a sequenceNumber property in the base 10 format which the causing the function processing to fail because of a formatting error which happens as the backend before entering the function code block.
Here is a sample message body generated by the event

Instead of using IoT Hub routing, use Events under IoT Hub and filter Device Connected and Device Disconnected Events` to track the event types. Choose your Service Bus Queue as an end point. Refer the following image for set up.

Disable the route set up using IoT Hub. The events generated with this approach will have a different template. Here is a sample message body generated by such event

You can then process the event generated using the below code and get the desired data
@app.service_bus_queue_trigger(arg_name="azservicebus", queue_name="lsayanaiot",
                           connection="lsayanaservicebus_SERVICEBUS") 
def lsayana_servicebus_queue_trigger(azservicebus: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    message_body = json.loads(azservicebus.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
    logging.info('Message body is %s', message_body)
    sequence_number = message_body['data']['deviceConnectionStateEventInfo']['sequenceNumber']
    logging.info('Python ServiceBus Queue trigger processed a message: %s',
                sequence_number)


I implemented this same approach few days back. Thanks for the answer, at least I know I'm not alone facing this. I'll accept this answer so that other user can see that this is known issue in Azure and , this answer is workaround

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/2071217/azure-functions-fail-to-decode-iothub-device-conne

I have tried your code and got the same error.
The SequenceNumber is expected to be an integer, but the incoming value is a string in a hexadecimal format.
Refer this MSDOC for Azure service bus sequence.
In your case the error arises when it tries to convert hexadecimal string directly to an integer in base 10.
You can retrieve and convert the SequenceNumber metadata field with below code.
I have refered this MSDOC to receive sequence number.
sequence_number_str = azservicebus.sequence_number
try:
sequence_number = int(sequence_number_str)
logging.info('Sequence Number: %d', sequence_number)
except ValueError as e:
logging.error('Invalid SequenceNumber format: %s', sequence_number_str)


The below code is with Azure Function
app = func.FunctionApp()
@app.service_bus_queue_trigger(
    arg_name="azservicebus", 
    queue_name="sampath",
    connection="sampath"
)
def servicebus_queue_trigger(azservicebus: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    try:
       
        message_body = azservicebus.get_body().decode('utf-8')
        logging.info('Python ServiceBus Queue trigger processed a message: %s', message_body)
        
       
        sequence_number_str = azservicebus.sequence_number
        try:
            
            sequence_number = int(sequence_number_str)
            logging.info('Sequence Number: %d', sequence_number)
        except ValueError as e:
            logging.error('Invalid SequenceNumber format: %s', sequence_number_str)

    except Exception as ex:
        logging.error('An error occurred: %s', str(ex))




Did you deployed this on Azure function app(V2 programming model)? Because it is failing before even entering in to my code, it is failing in microsoft's trigger code. Also the service bus message should be triggering this using IoTHub's device connection state message format/sample data like this link

yes I have deployed to azure function Here is the Output using message format/sample data of azure IoT Hub.

When you create a route in azure IoTHub to forward messages to service bus queue, it should be for 'Device Connection State Events' in  'Data Source'
